# Review Queue badge when there's something new to review

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications

In the main nav, the Inbox icon tells us with a red badge when a user has responded. The Trophy icon turns green when we have a new badge (or shows a green badge when we've received points.)

Was the Review Queue icon designed to be purposefully badge-less, even when there are new items to review? Wouldn't it be better for reviewers to know that there's something new to review, rather than having to manually check (or is the idea to distribute the actions among more reviewers by adding a little friction to the process)?